# Match multiple delimiters containg backslashes php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a php code that needs to be matched for any of the following string using preg_match using this code

```
if(preg_match('/(image/gif)|(image/jpg)|(image/jpeg)/',$between))
{
    echo "Match Found";
}

else

echo "Match Not Found";
```

but i get this error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\extension.php on line 38
```

Any help will be appreciated....I googled alot but couldn't find solution...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `/` as the [delimiter character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), so when it appears inside your regex you must escape it:

```
if(preg_match('/(image\/gif)|(image\/jpg)|(image\/jpeg)/',$between))
```

Alternatively, you can choose another delimiter:

```
if(preg_match('~(image/gif)|(image/jpg)|(image/jpeg)~',$between))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your preg_match pattern with this:

```
'/(image\/gif)|(image\/jpg)|(image\/jpeg)/'
```

You should always escape characters like /

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want `/` to be used inside regular expression - use `~` as a regex delimiter instead:

```
if(preg_match('~(image/gif)|(image/jpg)|(image/jpeg)~',$between))
               ^-----------                         ^--------
```

or even better:

```
if(preg_match('~image/(gif|jpe?g)~',$between))
```

Comment: @Salman A: right. Escaped `\/` is ugly, so I had written the answer in a bit "requirement-like" style ;-)